# Merging Pandas DataFrames; Inserting DataFrame2's rows into variable DataFrame1's rows/columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

This is a bit of a messy/challenging merge I'm trying to do here, and I have not been able to find a StackOverflow question applicable to this situation, so here goes:

DataFrame1 is in the format of my "end goal" (so that I ultimately want to stick data from DataFrame2 into DataFrame1), and looks something like the following:

| Profile: | Name: | CompanyName1: | JobTitle1: | JobSummary1: | CompanyName2: | JobTitle2: | JobSummary2: | CompanyName3: | JobTitle3: | JobSummary3: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Profile_0 | John Doe |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Profile_1 | Jane Smith |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Profile_2 | Mary Roe |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Profile_3 | Joe Shmo |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Note that the only columns populated in DataFrame1 above are Profile and Name.

DataFrame2 is as follows:

| Profile: | Name: | Job #: | CompanyName: | JobTitle: | JobSummary: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Profile_0 | John Doe | 1 | Firm A | Capacity a | Summary a |
| Profile_0 | John Doe | 2 | Firm B | Capacity b | Summary b |
| Profile_0 | John Doe | 3 | Firm C | Capacity c | Summary c |
| Profile_1 | Jane Smith | 1 | Firm X | Capacity x | Summary x |
| Profile_1 | Jane Smith | 2 | Firm Y | Capacity y | Summary y |
| Profile_1 | Jane Smith | 3 | Firm Z | Capacity z | Summary z |
| Profile_2 | Mary Roe | 1 | Firm P | Capacity p | Summary p |
| Profile_2 | Mary Roe | 2 | Firm Q | Capacity q | Summary q |

Here's where I am stuck. Through some Pandas magic, I am trying to arrive at the following:

| Profile: | Name: | CompanyName1: | JobTitle1: | JobSummary1: | CompanyName2: | JobTitle2: | JobSummary2: | CompanyName3: | JobTitle3: | JobSummary3: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Profile_0 | John Doe | Firm A | Capacity a | Summary a | Firm B | Capacity b | Summary b | Firm C | Capacity c | Summary c |
| Profile_1 | Jane Smith | Firm X | Capacity x | Summary x | Firm Y | Capacity y | Summary y | Firm Z | Capacity z | Summary z |
| Profile_2 | Mary Roe | Firm P | Capacity p | Summary p | Firm Q | Capacity q | Summary q |  |  |  |
| Profile_3 | Joe Shmo |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Does anyone have any idea how to do such a merge/join in Pandas? Any help would be greatly appreciated! :) Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strategy

1. reshape by `set_index()` and `unstack()`
2. rebuild df in new shape,  naming columns from multi-index

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Profile:    Name:   Job #:  CompanyName:    JobTitle:   JobSummary:
Profile_0   John Doe    1   Firm A  Capacity a  Summary a
Profile_0   John Doe    2   Firm B  Capacity b  Summary b
Profile_0   John Doe    3   Firm C  Capacity c  Summary c
Profile_1   Jane Smith  1   Firm X  Capacity x  Summary x
Profile_1   Jane Smith  2   Firm Y  Capacity y  Summary y
Profile_1   Jane Smith  3   Firm Z  Capacity z  Summary z
Profile_2   Mary Roe    1   Firm P  Capacity p  Summary p
Profile_2   Mary Roe    2   Firm Q  Capacity q  Summary q"""), sep="\t")

# change from long to wide
df = df.set_index(["Profile:","Name:","Job #:"]).unstack()
# rebuild df with values and columns from multi-index
df = pd.DataFrame(df.reset_index().values, columns=["Profile:","Name:"]+ [f"{c[0][:-1]}{c[1]}:" for c in df.columns])
```

### output

```
    Profile:       Name: CompanyName1: CompanyName2: CompanyName3:  JobTitle1:  JobTitle2:  JobTitle3: JobSummary1: JobSummary2: JobSummary3:
0  Profile_0    John Doe        Firm A        Firm B        Firm C  Capacity a  Capacity b  Capacity c    Summary a    Summary b    Summary c
1  Profile_1  Jane Smith        Firm X        Firm Y        Firm Z  Capacity x  Capacity y  Capacity z    Summary x    Summary y    Summary z
2  Profile_2    Mary Roe        Firm P        Firm Q           NaN  Capacity p  Capacity q         NaN    Summary p    Summary q          NaN
```

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. In trying out your solution, I've run into an issue - my DataFrame2 is just a Pandas DataFrame, so that when I go perform ```io.StringIO(DataFrame2)``` I get the following error: ```TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame```.  How exactly did you get that text from DataFrame2 into a format that io.StringIO() would accept?

Comment: I used that construct to convert table that was in SO post into a DF.  If you already have a DF not just text in webpage,  you don't use it ;-)

Comment: Wow, I cannot thank you enough! Very elegant solution incidentally. Thank you so much Rob! :)